# Idiomatic way to check if a value is inside an Enum

Tags: python, string, enums

I want to check if some *string value* exists in the *values set* of some Enum. Here is what I do:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(str, Enum):

    RED = "red"
    GREEN = "green"
    YELLOW = "yellow"

s = "red"
# s = "blue"

if any(s == c.value for c in Color):
    print(Color(s))
```

When I checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum-classes) I found that:

> The EnumMeta metaclass is responsible for providing the **contains**(), **dir**(), **iter**() and other methods that allow one to do things with an Enum class that fail on a typical class, such as list(Color) or some_enum_var in Color

But I want something different (checking existence for *values*). Is there a more pythonic way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test values against `_value2member_map_`, a dict attribute of the `Enum` sub-class that maps values to member classes, if you prefer not to clutter up your code with a `try-except` block:

```
if s in Color._value2member_map_:
    print(Color(s))
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.12 you'll be able to do this directly with `in`:

```
>>> "red" in Color
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: in 3.12 __contains__ will no longer raise TypeError, but will return True if
obj is a member or a member's value
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 'in': 'str' and 'EnumMeta'
```

While we're waiting for that, though, one option in addition to the one you've already found is to pass your value to the constructor, which will return the appropriate enum instance if there's a matching value, and raise `ValueError` otherwise.

```
>>> Color("red")
<Color.RED: 'red'>
>>> Color("asdf")
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: 'asdf' is not a valid Color
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more aesthetic implementation based on [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing)'s answer:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(str, Enum):

    RED = "red"
    GREEN = "green"
    YELLOW = "yellow"

    @staticmethod
    def values():
        # provide a meaningful named getter
        return Color._value2member_map_

s = "green"
# s = "blue"

# actual use becomes more clear
if s in Color.values():
    print(Color(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it into value list and check

```
"red" in [item.value for item in Color]
```